# How does one set up a local server

Tags: macos, iphone

How does one setup a local server on there Mac?

I know that MAMP can be used, but how does one set it up and connect to it locally?

Is MAMP the best way to go?

I am just after an easy to use local server for testing some code from an iOS device to a server(sending and requesting). Using my local network.

Answer (score 2):

MAMP is by far the easiest to install *AMP stack for the Mac.  My only complaint at this point is that the Apache Server version is still 2.0.*.  It's certainly simple enough to upgrade to 2.2.*, but it's an oversight considering the maturity of 2.2.*.

One nice aspect is the "throw away the folder" deinstallation process.  You can basically remove the MAMP folder and not worry about assorted changes being left behind in the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html). It includes everything you need for a local web server and easy setup is provided.

Comment: Why would you prefer XAMPP instead of MAMP?